# How to provide custom ActiveMQ Artemis configuration in kubernetes

Tags: activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

I am using the Artemis Cloud operator for deploying ActiveMQ Artemis in k8s cluster. I wanted to change some properties of brokers that were not available in ActiveMQ Artemis custom resources. Specifically, I wanted to change log level from INFO to WARN. Below were the options I came across.

1. Create a custom broker init image and have a script written to modify the `logging.properties` file
2. Add properties in `broker.properties` config map. (Which I am not able to because the config map is immutable)

My questions are

1. Whether my above observations are correct or not?
2. Whether any environmental variables present for this configuration?
3. Do we have better way to change this specific configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom broker init image and having a script written to modify the logging.properties file is the only supported way at the moment.
Soon ActiveMQ Artemis will move to SLF4J and after that ArtemisCloud will provides an easy way to change default logging properties. The idea to use a config map is great, feel free to raise an issue for the ArtemisCloud operator https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-operator/issues